# Drupal 7 newbie question: Node Access Permissions = disabled?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've worked in D6 for quite a while, and am just now dipping my toe into D7. I've got the basic installation working on my server and all's well; the only thing I don't understand is whether I should be bothered that admin/reports/status is telling me that Node Access Permissions are disabled. I understand that NAPs are nothing new to D7, and I've had occasion to rebuild the permissions once or twice in the past. But the new admin page calls out the disabled status explicitly, so I'm now wondering about stuff I hadn't wondered about before:

- What does it mean for these to be disabled (I'm logged in as user 1, if that matters)?
- Should I try to reconfigure the system or my server to get them enabled? What would I gain by having them enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything should be perfectly fine.

That only means that you are not using any module that is declaring node permissions so all nodes are visible for users with the view content permission.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's perfectly fine, but on my drupal site, since I upgraded to 7.2 (a security update it said) spammers are able to create new users (even though it's reserved to administrators now and the 2 only administrators did not login in between), create post with spam HTML links every day by the dozen!

Here is what it says on the status report:

Node Access Permissions Disabled
If the site is experiencing problems with permissions to content, you may have to rebuild the permissions cache. Rebuilding will remove all privileges to content and replace them with permissions based on the current modules and settings. Rebuilding may take some time if there is a lot of content or complex permission settings. After rebuilding has completed, content will automatically use the new permissions. Rebuild permissions

When I rebuild permission, it takes a few seconds only and the same message appears.